# How not to map some attributes of an entity in the return of a query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to build a super class that have a many attributes that is result of operations in a db query. But I have to make a lot of queries. So a I dont want to build a entity for each of these queries, is there a way that I can only map some of the attributes of the entity for each query?

Comment: It is better to create a class per such a query

Comment: But, sometimes, it just change some fields of a query to another.
For example, sometimes i need the sum of two columns and other times i need the multiplication, and i must have separate attributes for them. Is there a way to put these attributes in the same class?